# PHPUnit 3.4.15 exit if cookie getting without error

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, phpunit

If I called

```
$guest_identity = Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getCookie('guest_identity', $key);
```

or

```
$COOKIE['guest_identity'];
```

PHPUnit 3.4.15 exit function without error. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly there above code is supposed to throw an error or exception but it does not.

If this is the case then use one of these based on the type of error you are expecting to occur. If you pass the function null then the error handlers will be reset to the default values.

```
register_shutdown_function
set_error_handler
set_exception_handler
```

Comment: Thank you, but the fact that errors are not registered, and PHPUnit just quits and goes to create a report or shows time of processing and general statistics.

Comment: If an error is supposed to occur and you did all the functions above and you error_reporting(E_ALL); then for sure the error will occur as it would in any php script. If you are having trouble MakeGood is what I use for debugging PHPUnit test cases.